# Finding POI (points of interest) Within Given Radius using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point-of-interest

I have a table with x,y coordinates with the_geom column. Now I need to find the nodes (Points Of Interest) present in a given radius.

How do I find it?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT poi.name, poi.the_geom 
FROM poi, points 
WHERE ST_DWithin(points.the_geom, poi.the_geom, {your_distance});
```

Be sure to set up a spatial index in advance